# How to make flexbox div height to fit its content IF it's alone on its row but to be the same as its neighbours if there are other divs beside it?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Note that a lot of vertical space is added after the "bla bla bla" text:

[image: too much space]

In JSFiddle, that problem is not evident:

https://jsfiddle.net/leolucas1980/1u9zuhb2/1/#&togetherjs=ubHzeBFGaJ

The picture above was taken from the server I'm testing the page on:

http://3nano.fis.unb.br/test.html

I want that div's height to fit its content when it's wrapped and stay alone. On the other hand, its height must increase to be the same as the neighbor divs when width of the page increase and many divs stay side-by-side.

index.html:

```
<html position="fixed">
<head>
    <center><h1> TITLE </h1></center>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">
</head>
<body position="fixed">
<center>
<h1> TITLE </h1>
</center>
<div class="container">
<div class="menu">
<div class="menucontainer">
<div class="menudiv">MENU 1</div>
<div class="menudiv">MENU 2 </div>
<div class="menudiv">MENU 3 </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content" align="center"> <iframe name="contentframe"
src="testframe.html"
style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0">
</iframe> </div>
<div class="links" align="center">
<div class="linkscontainer">
<h2>LINKS</h2>
<div class="linksdiv"> <iframe src="testframe.html"
style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0">
</iframe> </div>
<h2>CONTACT</h2>
<div class="linksdiv"> <iframe src="testframe.html"
style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0">
</iframe> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<footer> </footer>
<div> <br>
<small> bla bla bla </small> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.css

```
html {
       height: 100%;
       margin-left: 20px;
       margin-right: 20px;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border:1px solid;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu {
    min-width: 200px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border:1px solid;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px){
    .menu{max-width: 160px;}
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 400px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: right;
    flex: 2;
    border:1px solid;
}

.links {
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float:right;
    flex: 1;
    border:1px solid;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px){
    .links{max-width: 300px;}
}

.menucontainer {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border:1px solid;
}

.menudiv {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid;
}

.linkscontainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border:1px solid;
}

.linksdiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    min-height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    border:1px solid;
}

footer{
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

testframe.html:

```
<html>

<p>
bla bla bla <br>
bla bla bla <br>
bla bla bla <br>
bla bla bla <br>
bla bla bla <br>
bla bla bla <br>
</p>

</html>
```